# Install two versions of OpenCv for two versions of Visual-Studio?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

I already have OpenCv2.2 installed for Visual Studio 2010. Recently I installed Visual studio 2013 and wanted to install OpenCv2.4.9 for it. I was wondering if it is possible to have both versions on my computer without having problem?

Is it possible to run a project with the older version on the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes, no problem to have both on the same box. the dlls are versioned, just add the 2.4.9 folders to the path.
2. no, you can't run the old exe with the new dlls. each binary depends on the dlls it was build with.
3. (you did not ask this, but probably the fastest way to migrate a vs project from 2.2 to 2.4.9 is to open the vcproj file with a *text* editor, and change the old locations/names globally there. much better than clicking through 100ds of dialog boxes)